# System.Attribute exclude duplicate values

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, custom-attributes

I have a list property which is decorated with an System.Attribute class . Is it possible to include a check at the attribute level for the list to contain only distinct values ?

```
[ConfigSettingList(typeof(string),Description="Contains a list of supported handheld devices . Default is the below list .")]
        public List<string> HandHeldDevices
        {
            get
            {
                if (_handHeldDevices == null)
                {
                    _handHeldDevices = new List<string> { "Android", "webOS", "iPhone", "iPad", "iPod", "BlackBerry", "IEMobile", "Opera Mini" };
                }
                return _handHeldDevices;
            }
        }
        private List<string> _handHeldDevices;
```

ConfigSettingList inherits from System.Attribute . I want to check for distinct values .

Comment: What do you meant by that? Could you elaborate ?

Comment: use dictionary instead

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which doesn't allows duplicate elements.